# Unexpected keyword argument 'show_dtype'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to plot my model with the data types with the following the code:

```py
plot_model(model, to_file='model/model.png', show_dtype=True, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

However, I get an error that `show_dtype` is not an acceptable parameter even though it appears on the TensorFlow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time that I have run into this issue. It seems that this may be due to having an earlier release if you downloaded it from Anaconda Forge rather than something else like Pip. It is a simple fix, however.

Basically, you need to go into the library source file and edit it to the current version that is shown on the TensorFlow documentation page.

The link to the GitHub page that you will copy the Python code from is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py#L278-L348

Afterwards, head to your library path and paste that Python code there.
For example, my path is the following: `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/ml/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py`. Yours should be something similar.